# Taking max of absolute values of two df columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The questions looks very easy but I did not find a suitable intuitive answer.
Suppose I have a df.

`df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [-1,2,3], "B": [-2, 8, 1], "C": [-5, -6, 7]})`

I want to create a column 'D' which gives the max of absolute values between 'A' and 'B'.
In short what I am expecting is kind of the following form.

`df["D"] = (df["A"].abs(), df["B"].abs()).max()`

or
`df["D"] = max(df["A"].abs(), df["B"].abs())`

or
`df["D"] = max(abs(df["A"]), abs(df["B"])`

Obviously, none of them works because the syntax is taken from SAS and Excel.
Help please.

Comment: Are you expecting - `[2, 8, 3]` to be your output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, You want this:

```
df['D'] = df[['A', 'B']].abs().max(axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

```
   A  B  C  D
0 -1 -2 -5  2
1  2  8 -6  8
2  3  1  7  3
```